# jQuery Chained and bootstrapping

Tags: jquery, json, chained

I am using the jQuery Chained plugin here: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained by Mika Tuupola.

Have the following code:

```
    $("#province").remoteChained({
        parents: "#country",
        url: "../wp-content/plugins/plugin/api/stateprov-json.php",
        bootstrap: {
            "AB" : "Alberta",
            "BC" : "British Columbia"
        }
```

My stateprov-json.php file will dynamically return provinces or states as JSON, based on passed country ("CAN" or "USA").

If the user changes the country, how can I dynamically update the bootstrap argument?

Answer (score 1):

The bootstrap is only to avoid an initial request. The select will automatically be populated from the JSON returned from stateprov-json.php.

As long as:

```
../wp-content/plugins/plugin/api/stateprov-json.php?country=USA
```

returns:

```
{
    "AL": "Alabama",
    "AK": "Alaska"
}
```